# How to change the Laravel environment while doing selenium testing in codeception?

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, testing, codeception

I am using codeception to write selenium tests. This specific suite does not have Laravel5 module. I have a test database that I use when doing the functional or acceptance testing. But when I am writing those test I can set the app environment to testing (probably codeception would do it automatically when I require the Laravel5 module) but when I am running selenium tests, how can I make my Laravel app to switch the environment to testing?

Question: How can I switch the environment to testing while running selenium tests with codeception?

Answer (score 2):

I do it by running my tests with phpunit (as I suppose you do as well). If you did it, you just have to put your configuration on your phpunit.xml file.

If you are doing any other way, you'll just need to change your .env file with your testing configuration.